# Can you keep separate Sent folders in Gmail for each of your custom SMTP servers?

Tags: gmail, smtp

Is there a way to keep separate Sent folders in Gmail for each of your custom SMTP servers?

I already use labels to differentiate them by the way, but 2 Sent Mail folders would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.

You can create a filter that looks at the from: field and applies a specific label. You'd then need labels for each (sent-mail1, sent-mail2, etc.).

The messages will still end up in "Sent Mail" as well, of course.

I do something similar. I have filters to have all messages where a specific e-mail is in the from: or to: get a label for that address.

Comment: Ya I'm doing this now too but would be ice to have a special Sent folder separate at the top.  I think it's not possible though so I'll accept this unless something better is posted later.

Comment: You could use the nested labels feature from Gmail Labs and have labels Sent/Mail1, Sent/Mail2 and they could all collapse to a "label" called Sent.

Comment: @Al Everett: That helps slightly but still a little messy.  I had to call the folder Sent! by the way for nested folders because you can't create a label for Sent because the name is reserved.

Comment: Yeah, there's no perfect solution. (Well, short of getting on the Board of Directors of Google and demanding the feature.)

Comment: @Al Everett: I'll get right on that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with just using labels you can go into Settings > Labels and hide the system Sent Mail label to avoid going there by mistake.